# Clicking on Navigator Entry hides my nodes

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

hen the xPage loads the render code works just fine.  However, when the user clicks on Register for e-Statements they both get hidden until I refresh the page manually.  I tried doing a full update and other parts of my code fail trying to access some java beans.

The code used for the render is a in my global javascript library.

Any thoughts?

```
<xe:navigator id="navigator1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicContainerNode label="Register for e-Statements"
                submitValue="RegisterForEstatements" enabled="true">
             <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:myEStatements.renderStatements()}]]>
                </xe:this.rendered>
            </xe:basicContainerNode>

            <xe:basicLeafNode label="View My e-Statements" onClick="linkToEstatements();">
                <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:myEStatements.renderStatements()}]]>
                </xe:this.rendered>
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>

        <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="navigator1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:                      
            if( context.getSubmittedValue() == "RegisterForEstatements" )
            {
                sessionScope.put( "dialogAcceptEStatementTitle", "Accept e-Statements!" );
                var dialogAcceptEstatements = getComponent( "dlgAcceptEStatements" );
                dialogAcceptEstatements.show();
                return "";
            }        
            sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsTitle", "Oopps!" );
            sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsMessage", "\nThis Feature Has Not Been Enabled Yet!" );
            var dialogOops = getComponent( "dialogOops" );
            dialogOops.show();
            return "";

            }]]>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        }]]>
</xe:navigator>
```

Here is the additional code from the Javascript Library.  FYI, the properProfile is a JavaBean that appears to be null when I click the navigator.  I have defined the bean scope as request and tried session neither change the error.

```
var myEStatements = 
{
//  If the property receives Statements return true to display the e-Statement Links
//  in the occ navigator
"renderStatements" : function() 
{
    var result = false;
    try 
    {
        result = aPropertyProfile.getStatementCoupon_1().equalsIgnoreCase( "Statement" );
    } catch (e) 
    {
        print(e.message);
    }
    return result;
},

//  Fetch the e-Statement Accept Message
"getEStatementAcceptMessage" : function()
{
    var eStatementAcceptMessage = "";
    try
    {
        eStatementAcceptMessage = eStarService.getEStatementAcceptMessage();
    }  catch(e)
    {
        print( e.message );
    }
    return eStatementAcceptMessage;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to show the relevant code in your JS library and Java bean - otherwise it is guessing game. if myEstatements is a managed bean, you could do EL directly like #{myEstatements.renderStatements} if your function is boolean isRenderStatements() {..} (but that's not the issue here)

Comment: I added the additional code.  Curious if you have thoughts as to why my beans disappear when the navigator is clicked.

Comment: digging deeper... aPropertyProfile smells like "Application" profile? You might want to add a computed field to your code to return that value to see if it is changing in a way you didn't expect

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  aPropertyProfile as a Bean I create.  I have two beans that I try to access in this custom control that seem to go away when I click an item in the navigator.  I get the error aPropertyProfile is not found.  Not sure how as all the code is in the same custom control and works when the page is loaded etc.  If I change the click event from partial refresh to Full Update I get the same error.

Comment: What I'm trying to say: show the value of the bean *directly* in a computed text. Looking at the "a" prefix it might suggest to be an "application" scope variable? Do others interfere? Does it timeout? To get to the bottom you need to see if that variable changes (which I suspect) - then the problem is inside the bean - and you need to update the question with the bean code too